# jQuery stops working after ajax loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, reload

#### some info

I'm working on a webpage that can load data on multiple layouts, so user can choose which one is best. It can be loaded in a list or a cards like interface, and the data is loaded using ajax.
In this page I also have a notifier for new messages that the user received. The ajax function is new, and when page was loaded by the php scripts, the **js** script (that add a badge with the number of unread messages to a link on a menu item) was working ok.

I'm using **HTML5**, **PHP**, **jQuery** and a mySQL DB.
jQuery is imported onto the HTML using

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"> </script>
So it's a recent version.

#### the problem

Now, when I load the data onto the page using ajax, the **js** script won't work anymore. I had the same issue with another **js** script and I managed to solve it by using the delegate event binder.
But my unread messages updater runs on a time interval, using

```
<body onload="setInterval('unread()', 1000)">
```

**the unread() js is quite simple:**

```
function unread() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu_item').load('ajax_countNewMsgs.php');
  });
}
```

it calls a **php** script which grabs the unread msgs count from the DB and echo into a element that jQuery will point. Hope I'm being clear.
The problem is that I cannot figure out how I would call a timed event using delegate. Without much hope I've tried

```
$(document).on('ready()','#menu_item', function () {
  $(this).load('ajax_countNewMsgs.php');
});
```

That didn't work.

I read many posts about **js** stop working after changes in the DOM, but, again, I couldn't figure out a way to solve that, nor found a similar question.
Any help or tips would be highly appreciated.

EDITED to change second php script's name

## 2nd EDIT - trying to make things clearer

I tried the way @carter suggested

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function unread(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax_countNewMsgs.php',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response){
        $('#menu_item').html(response);
      },
      error: function(response){
        //no error handling at this time
      }
    });
  }

  setInterval(unread(), 1000);
});
```

the **ajax_countNewMsgs.php** script connects to the DB, fetch the unread messages, and echoes the number of unread messages.
If I try to apply the ajax reponse to another element, say, the <body> the results are as expected: at each 1 sec , the body html is changed. So the function is working.
As I said, none of my JS changes the #menu_item. Actuallly this element is part of another php scritp (menu.php) which is imported to the top of the page.
the page structure is this way:

```
<html>
 <head>
  some tags here
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php include (php/menu.html); ?>this will include menu with the #menu_item element here
  <div id='wrapper'>
     <div id='data'>
       here goes the data displayed in two ways (card and list like). Itens outside div wrapper are not being changed.
     </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Even though the elemente is not being rewritten js cannot find it to update it's value.
It's not the full code, but I think you can see what is being done.

Comment: Are you overwriting the DOM element where the JS was defined?

Comment: Sometimes I have to delegate to fix this type of problem, but generally you have to call any javascript related to content after the page is loaded. Any JS inside of that newly loaded html won't fire unless you specifically invoke it yourself. So in your ajax success you could call `setInterval('unread()', 1000)`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Are you overwriting the `#menu_item` element at any time? As @ShanRobertson has pointed out, that may be killing `setInterval()`. When **you're done overwriting** the element just call `setInterval(unread, 1000)`.

Comment: @developerwjk no, the ajax only changes a div that doesn't have the js codes.

Comment: @Shan Robertson, I'd try that, but I really don't know where to put the setInterval (may I use jQuery to "re-attach" it to the body tag?)

Comment: @user3558931 The only function which rewrite #menu_item is the unread() function. But setInterval is attached to the &lt;body&gt; tag, which is never reloaded.

Comment: I was quite sure it isn't being overwritten @developerwjk... But if it is? Any ideas on how to solve that? 
I mean, the ajax function which load the page data isn't supposed to reload/rewrite menu's elements, but maybe it is doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('ready()','#menu_item', function () {
```

is an invalid event listener.  If you wanted to be made aware of when the DOM is ready you should do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

However I don't think that is actually what you want.  Your function `unread` will fire repeatedly but it attaches an event listener everytime.  Instead if you want to make an ajax call every so many seconds after initial page load, you should do something like this (dataType property could be html, json, etc. pick your poison):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function makeCall(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax_countNewMsgs.php',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response){
        //handle your response
      },
      error: function(response){
        //handle your error
      }
    });
  }

  setInterval(makeCall, 1000);
});
```

Comment: thank you! I tried to use your suggestion, but I don't know how to handle this function response. I want the response from this ajax request to fill the #menu_item html... How should I write that on the success: function(response)?
And I really think, even the menu item don't being changed by the data loading, that I have to change the way I refer to the element.

Comment: i.e. in a ajax search function that stopped working after the ajax data loading, I managed to solve by change
$('#bt_search').click(function() {.... to
$(document).on('click', '#bt_search', function(){

Comment: `$('#menu_item').html(response);`

Comment: ok thanks, @carter... that was pretty obvious, sorry my lameness.
anyway, the problem wasn't fixed. I think the problem is Jquery finding the element. I know that the script still running, and if I use another div to receive the response, the script works. But I can't access the original element.

Comment: now I know that the function is being called, @carter, because if I change the div which that will receive the result to another one (the wrapper) the div is changed, and I can see through firefox's inspect element the code blinking, at each change, or 1000ms.
Any thoughts? thanks in advance.

Comment: @PedroLapenta sorry I don't know what you are trying to do.  The code I posted will make ajax call every 1000 ms and it will expect the result to be HTML.  Please post all of your code.

Comment: I edited the original post, with more info and how I tried to use your code, @carter.
The scripts are working, and even though the element it's not being changed (as far as I know) JS cannot find it. I think the that is the problem

Comment: Please be clear.  What is php script you included?  Is that the initial page being loaded or are you calling that php script with every ajax call?  Start over from scratch and do this format:  "Here is my initial page code: blah blah, here is my js code: blah blah, here is my php script being called every second: blah blah."

Comment: had to take another approach, as my deadline was too close. 
I realized that the js couldn't find the #menu_item. I tested it with

    if ( $('#menu_item').length ) {
      alert("ok");
    }

the element was there. But I couldn't bind any other event to it, using it's __id__. So I tried to add a __class__ instead (beNotified). The js managed to find the class, so problem solved for me (right now). 
I'll try to investigate more and, if customer allows, I'll post the entire code here, as you asked. I just asked his permission. 
Thank you, @carter, for your attention and effort to help.

Comment: `$('#menu_item').length` will always be true since it could have a zero length.  this would be the check you want: `$('#menu_item').length > 0` My guess is that you have used an id more than once or some other html related mistake. Just post a comment back here if you want to pursue further.

Answer (score 0):

**remove** that on your `unread` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

**WHY?**

The Document is **already** "ready" and this document state will only fired 1x - After that the "ready state" will never ever called. Use follwing syntax:

```
jQuery(function($){
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip. It makes sense and I fixed it.
But it doesn't solve my problem...